# Nuxt 3: $fetch vs useAsyncData on user's data fetching?

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt3

New on Nuxt, I'm wanna fetch a route like "api/auth/me" when:

- The apps starts with a plugin:
- When I wanna control the auth on a private page (with a middleware)

The auth/me is looking is a cookie is here with a JWT. And I want it to fetch before the app showing (is that possible?).

The app using SSR mode on home page but SPA on others

my questions are:

**1) should I use only $fetch here because it's related on user data or I can't use useAsyncData ?**

Maybe I miss understood because I don't with with what kind of data we can use each ($fetch, useFetch, useAsyncData etc...)

Here my plugin:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
    const { me } = await useAuth();

    await me();
});
```

My middleware (when it's a private page):

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async () => {
    const { me } = useAuth();
    await me();

    const authUser = useAuthUser();

    if (!authUser.value) return navigateTo({ name: "login" });
    return
});
```

and this is the "me" function from the useAuth composable:

```
const me = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await useAsyncData('me', () => $fetch("/api/users/me", {
        headers: useRequestHeaders(["cookie"]) as HeadersInit,
    }))

    if (error.value) {
        setUser(null)
    }

    if (data.value) {
        setUser(data.value.data.user)
    } else {
        setUser(null) 
    }

    return authUser.value
};
```

or maybe I should do it like this? :

```
const me = async () => {
    const res = await $fetch("/api/users/me", {
        headers: useRequestHeaders(["cookie"]) as HeadersInit,
    })

    if (res.data.user) {
        setUser(res.data.user)
    }

    else {
        setUser(null) 
    }

return await authUser.value
```

};

**2) is that normal when, if I inspect the html (source code), I see this ?**
(user infos, and stripe public key)

```
<script type="application/json" id="__NUXT_DATA__" data-ssr="true">[["Reactive",1],{"data":2,"state":3,"_errors":20,"serverRendered":21,"path":22},{},{"$s__nuxt_devtools__":4,"$suser":6},{"timeSsrStart":5},1693686497320,{"_id":7,"name":8,"email":9,"orders":10,"created_at":19,"__v":18},"64ebbd6a785faa1629ff6c20","John snow","xxxxxx@outlook.com",[11],{"_id":12,"order_id":13,"customer_id":14,"customer_email":9,"customer_name":8,"status":15,"created_at":16,"invoice":17,"__v":18},"64ebbd6zzzzz62xxxx1d","pi_3NjqKxxxxxB","cus_OWu9kp4bMpkbmI","paid",1693171030,"in_1NjxxxxEmOzB",0,1693171050184,{},true,"/"]</script> <script>window.__NUXT__={};window.__NUXT__.config={public:{stripe:{key:"pk_test_51IEdxxxx9neEA28xxxxv4",options:{}}},app:{baseURL:"/",buildAssetsDir:"/_nuxt/",cdnURL:""}}</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this might be related to your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76839593/21341655

Comment: Hi thanks Ive already seen this post before but needing more precision because I dont get why I should use usefetch (or useAsyncData) for user info fetch. I tested $fetch and useAsyncData and understood that data is fetching on both side but i dont understand if I have to (for my needs) fetch using front/back (usefetch/useAsyncData) or front ($fetch). Why would I need to fetch on the backend side also? For SEO reason only? Or something else

Comment: @ReaganM forgot to tag you

Comment: The recommended way of fetching the data is the `useFetch` as it is a short-hand of `useAsync` and `fetch`. And by default it runs on the server and transferred to the client, if you want to only run it on the client, there is an option for it. The `$fetch` During SSR data is fetched twice, once on the server and once on the client. To answer your comment on why would you need to fetch on the back-end side, it is optional depending on your needs.

Comment: @ReaganM if I put SSR false on the /me route, the front-end isn't fetching enough early. Because if I don't wait the end of the page load, I can click on the private menu and so, the app thinks I'm not authenticated. If I put SSR mode, it works as I want but I don't know if i'm suposed to fetch user data with SSR